# What is the recommended solution to resolve these errors when trying to install guzzlehttp?

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

When trying to install guzzlehttp/guzzle

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

I get the following problem messages

```
Using version ^7.5 for guzzlehttp/guzzle
./composer.json has been updated 
Running composer update guzzlehttp/guzzle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies  
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
                                              
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.5 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, 7.5.x-dev].
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, ..., 7.5.x-dev] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.9 || ^2.4 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[dev-master, 1.9.0, 1.x-dev, 2.4.0, ..., 2.4.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but the package is fixed to 2.1.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.                                                                                                                                                     
  Problem 2                                                                                                                                                           
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, ..., 7.5.x-dev] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.9 || ^2.4 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[dev-master, 1.9.0, 1.x-dev, 2.4.0, ..., 2.4.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but the package is fixed to 2.1.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.                                           
    - codeception/module-phpbrowser 1.0.2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3|^7.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, 7.5.x-dev].
    - codeception/module-phpbrowser is locked to version 1.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.                                                       

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

I need to use the stable version of guzzle.

I have read about it and it is suggested to remove the `composer.lock` file in order to run `composer install` or `composer update`. But I would like to know What is the recommended solution in this scenario?

Comment: Try running `composer update` before you try installing it? Though you already have guzzlehttp/guzzle thanks to `codeception/module-phpbrowser`. `codeception/module-phpbrowser` is up to 2.0.3, so you might want to install the newer version of that first

Comment: What happens if you run `composer update guzzlehttp/psr7` before requiring the new package? Also, if you already installed `codeception/module-phpbrowser` which requires Guzzle, why do you need to install it a second time?

Comment: hello. thanks for comment. Indeed. I was unaware that `module-phpbrowser` includes `guzzle`. So I could only use it in my app

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conflict between the version of guzzlehttp/guzzle required by the root composer.json file and the version required by codeception/module-phpbrowser. composer.json file requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.5, which is only satisfied by version 7.5.0 and 7.5.x-dev. However, codeception/module-phpbrowser requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3|^7.0, which is only satisfied by version 7.5.0 and 7.5.x-dev as well. Try this one `composer update -w`,this will update all packages and their dependencies, including those that are locked to a specific version in the composer.lock file. I hope this help. (PS: backup you file before you try any thing , such as the original json files)

Comment: That looks strange to me, as the error is thrown by `guzzlehttp/psr7`